# Data is not display in the real-time database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I went through all the steps according to the documents, read and writing to the real-time database works well but the data is not displayed in the database, how to fix this?

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'
```

```
private fun readMessageOnRD(){
    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val value = snapshot.getValue<String>()
            Log.d("TAG", "value of firebase is $value")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled: " ,error.toException())
        }
    })
}

private fun writeMessageOnRD(value : String){
    database = Firebase.database
    myRef = database.getReference("message")
    Log.d("TAG","write value is $value")
    myRef.setValue(value)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("TAGggwp", "writeMessageOnRD: $it")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("TAGggwp", "exeption is $it")
        }
}

IconButton(
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Bottom)
        .weight(0.10f)
        .padding(bottom = 4.dp),
    onClick = {
        if (textFieldState.isNotEmpty()) {
            writeMessageOnRD(textFieldState)
            readMessageOnRD()
        }
    }
```

```
"rules": {
  ".read": "true",
  ".write": "true",
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is any of the `onCancelled` or `onFailure` called? If yes, what's the message?

Comment: Since there is a `message` in the database and its value is empty, it seems that the `textFieldState` value in your code is likely an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using your database url, add this line

```
val database = Firebase.database("your database URL").getReference("message")
```